# How to change the for loop in the code to give me an additional column in my dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes.
df1['column'] has 70k unique text values.
df2['column'] has 20 unique text values.

I want to find the closest synonym for all the 70k values by looking at the 20 values in df2['column'].
and want an additional column in df1, which has the best synonym for that word.

I found a code where you could do semantic search and gives the top 5 synonyms with a score.

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util
import torch

embedder = SentenceTransformer('paraphrase-distilroberta-base-v1')

# Corpus with example sentences
corpus = ind_type_new['Industry_type_new_list'].to_list()
corpus_embeddings = embedder.encode(corpus, convert_to_tensor=True)

# Query sentences:
queries = df_test['industry_types_test'][df_test['industry_types_test'] != ''].head(50)

# Find the closest 5 sentences of the corpus for each query sentence based on cosine similarity
top_k = min(1, len(corpus))
for query in queries:
    query_embedding = embedder.encode(query, convert_to_tensor=True)

    # We use cosine-similarity and torch.topk to find the highest 5 scores
    cos_scores = util.pytorch_cos_sim(query_embedding, corpus_embeddings)[0]
    top_results = torch.topk(cos_scores, k=top_k)

    print("\n\n======================\n\n")
    print("Query:", query)
    print("\nTop 5 most similar sentences in corpus:")

    for score, idx in zip(top_results[0], top_results[1]):
        print(corpus[idx], "(Score: {:.4f})".format(score))
```

The output of the code is as below***

```
======================
Query: Farming

Top 5 most similar sentences in corpus:
Agriculture (Score: 0.4851)
Construction (Score: 0.4436)
Manufacturing (Score: 0.4099)
Property (Score: 0.3876)
Importer (Score: 0.3616)


======================


Query: Shopping Centre 

Top 5 most similar sentences in corpus:
Consumer Services (Score: 0.4105)
Hospitality (Score: 0.4089)
Business Services (Score: 0.3898)
Wholesale / Distribution (Score: 0.3863)
Retail (Score: 0.3625)


======================


Query: Retail Food

Top 5 most similar sentences in corpus:
Retail (Score: 0.7708)
Consumer Services (Score: 0.4168)
Accommodation and Food Services (Score: 0.4085)
Business Services (Score: 0.3977)
Insurance (Score: 0.3870)
```

All I want to do is get another column in the 1st dataframe, which would be the best matching synonym for that column when compared with the 2nd dataframe.

For example the result would look like
| Industry Type | Match |
|--------|-------|
| Farming | Agriculture |
|Shopping centre|Consumer Services|

Could you please suggest what amends should I make to the code to get the desired out?

Comment: First of all, simplify your code example.  Do you want to know how to extract the top answer from the  code shown or do you want to know how to take the top answer and make a new column in the data frame?  The rule of SO state one question per query, so please clarify.  Refer to [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming we are adding a column called "Match" to `df_test`:

```
matches = dict() #dictionary to save the mappings
top_k=1 #because we only want the top match
for query in queries:
    query_embedding = embedder.encode(query, convert_to_tensor=True)
    cos_scores = util.pytorch_cos_sim(query_embedding, corpus_embeddings)[0]
    top_results = torch.topk(cos_scores, k=top_k)
    matches[query] = corpus[int(top_results[1])]

df_test["Match"] = df_testd["industry_types_test"].map(matches) #add column to df based on dictionary values
```

Sample output:

```
>>> df_test["industry_types_test"]
0            Farming
1    Shopping Centre
Name: industry_types_test, dtype: object

>> df_test[["industry_types_test", "Match"]]
  industry_types_test                             Match
0             Farming                       Agriculture
1     Shopping Centre      Arts and Recreation Services
```

Comment: That did give me a "Match" column but its all NaN values. For example *Farming* should have resulted in *Agriculture* but it was NaN. The only time it was not NaN was when all the other columns in the dataframe were empty (NaN).

Comment: Edited the last line typecasting the index to an `int`. Hopefully that helps - it works for me.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't change anything. It is still the same result. The match column is NaN, and the only time it is not NaN and has values is when the industry_types_test column is NaN.

Comment: It works for me. You may want to provide examples of your input data frames.

Comment: The input dataframe "df_test" looks like this : https://ibb.co/ZB49STg
The input dataframe "ind_type_new" looks like this.  https://ibb.co/P51pnHg
The code and the output look like this: https://ibb.co/cryyxnh

Comment: Modified a bit using some of your input - see the edited answer.

Comment: Awesome! That's exactly what I wanted. I gave the result I wanted. Thanks a ton for your help and following up on this question :)))))))))))))))))))))